# Joomla shows always the home page even if direct to other pages

Tags: articles

I have the newest version of Joomla and every was working fine during 2 yeas. 
Since 2 weeks ago any menu entry shows only the home page.  If I change the home page and write "Under Construction" on it, the system saves the changes but does not show them. If I create a new menu with a new article, the system shows always the old homepage and not the new article. I read everything about SEO but it did not help. 
The problem can be shown on this site: http://www.c2ny.org/

Please help!
Martin Bächtold

Comment: That is indeed strange.  Have you performed any upgrades to hardware or software in the stack?  PHP, Apache, Linux, Joomla 3.5, etc?  Maybe migrate data or anything which could have been a catalyst?  I did notice your submenus are SEF while the main menu items are not.  You have an .htaccess configured?

Comment: I am afraid that looking only from the front-end point-of-view, we cannot give you any reasonable answer. There are just too many variables involved, that without admin access no one can tell what's wrong for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using the T3 framework. I've had very bad experiences with that framework - just now working on an old site using T3. Strange things happen, and some things cannot be set the usual way but must be set in the template options instead. Have you checked those?

What comes up in your main content now is nothing but "blog-featured". A module?
So maybe an issue with your positions - only this module position is displayed, none of the main content at all.